How to I paste the word I copied before deleting something?
I am a new Vim motions user, I use it in VsCode. The most annoying thing that I run into constantly is that when I try the following:
const animal = "dog";

const pet = "cat";

I want to replace the cat with the dog.
What I'm currently doing is:

yanking dog using yiw and then
going to the cat and deleting inside the "" with di" or ci" then
going to my system clipboard history and going to the previously copied dog and the pasting it.

Is there a better way to do that without accessing the system clipboard?

This question is similar to: Clipboard is reset after first paste in Visual Mode. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

There's a great plugin that gives a new normal mode command (gr) to do just this: https://github.com/vim-scripts/ReplaceWithRegister?tab=readme-ov-file

The standard way to do that is:

move to the dog part (within or before "dog")
yi" to yank/copy dog
move to the cat part (within or before "cat")
vi" to select the cat
P to replace cat by dog (and keep having dog in the clipboard)

Summary: To replace something with the content of the keyboard the proposal is to visually select the part to be replaced and to execute P or p (depending if you want your clipboard to stay the same or to get the content of what has been replaced respectively).

If you don't use P to keep the unnamed (") register intact, you can find the previous yank in the "0 register.
